Audio play button firing phantom second click when currentTime is modified programmatically, preventing playback
When I pause an Audio and set it's currentTime, it does something weird. when I press a button that controls the .paused state of the Audio, it seems to click again automatically, preventing the audio from playing. Why?
Additionally, if I set the currentTime again, it decides to stop clicking the play button twice. this happens on and off every time I set the currentTime. it can be demonstrated with this code. (slowed audio is only because the example audio is too short).
<!doctype html><html><body>
  <button id="play" disabled>play</button>
  <button id="idk">load audio</button>
  <script>
    var clicks = 0; console.clear();
    idk = document.getElementById("idk");
    idk.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{
      aud = new Audio("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3")
      aud.addEventListener('canplaythrough', init);
    }, {once: true});
    function init(){
      /**/aud.playbackRate = 0.25;//only to lengthen the audio to give you time.
      playButton = document.getElementById("play");
      playButton.disabled = false;
      idk.innerText = "pause and set time to 1";
      playButton.addEventListener("click", e=>{
        if(aud.paused){
          aud.play();
          playButton.innerText = "pause";
        }else{
          aud.pause();
          playButton.innerText = "play";
        }
        //Nothing different between duplicate click events, logging it takes up space
        console.log(clicks++, aud.paused, /*e*/);//clicks++ to tell apart logs.
      });
      idk.addEventListener("click", e=>{
        console.log("Rightmost element clicked");
        if(!aud.paused){ aud.pause(); playButton.innerText = "play"; }
        aud.currentTime = 1;
      });
    }
  </script>
</body></html>

See live example (removed event logging due to pollution of console)
simply click load audio, then click play once permitted, and finally click on pause and set time to 1.
after such, the click event will be fired twice per actual click (as seen in the log), preventing the audio from playing. the only way to fix it is to click pause and set time to 1 again, and attempt clicking play. You will be successful, but if you click the right button again, you will face this issue again.
I also noticed that the double-clicking turns into quadruple-clicking when modified slightly, still causing the issue, as 4 clicks is an even number.
<!doctype html><html><body>
  <button id="play">play</button>
  Control+Click to pause the audio and change it's currentTime value
  <script>
    var clicks = 0; console.clear();    
    playButton = document.getElementById("play");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{
      /**/window.aud = new Audio("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3");
      aud.addEventListener('canplaythrough', ()=>{
        playButton.style.color = "#080";
        /**/aud.playbackRate = 0.25;//only to lengthen the audio to give you time.
        playButton.addEventListener("click", e=>{
          if(e.ctrlKey){
            if(!aud.paused){ aud.pause(); playButton.innerText = "play"; }
            aud.currentTime = 1;
            return;
          }
          if(aud.paused){
            aud.play();
            playButton.innerText = "pause";
          }else{
            aud.pause();
            playButton.innerText = "play";
          }
          //Nothing different between duplicate click events, logging it takes up space
          console.log(clicks++, aud.paused, /*e*/);//clicks++ to tell apart logs.
        });
      });
    }, {once: true});
  </script>
</body></html>

See live example (removed event logging due to pollution of console)
to use the second example, use CTRL+Click as the pause and set time to 1 button.
in both examples, running aud.play(); in the console seems to work, but still doesn't allow the play/pause button to act and double clicks them. Setting aud.currentTime in the console (after it has been set an even number of times) has no effect, and neither does having the code set aud.currentTime twice in succession. The user has to click it and then click it again.
This occurs on Chrome Beta 127.0.6533.94 on ChromeOS, as well as Chrome 127.0.6533.85 and Firefox 129.0 on Android 14. I Can't get it to work at all on non-EU iOS.
HOWEVER...
Safari 17.3 on MacOS Sonoma (via Browserling, if any difference made) appears to work as expected.
Sorry in advance, if that's insufficient testing, or I made a really obvious mistake.
This is a simplification pinpoint of a bug occurring on a larger codebase (minus "base", but still significantly larger than these codes). Some of the proposed changes might not be compatible with my case, therefore, I would very much like to (and prefer to, Even without fixes, but would be happy to recieve a fix as well) understand simply-put what is actually happening and why. If a fix is included, please change very little if possible. all i know is when currentTime is changed, the code doesnt function as expected, and when otherwise, it pauses and works perfectly. No extraneous events are being listened to, as found in DevTools, async is left there by accident, it is a part of the real codebase.
The code including "idk" is the focus, and the other is just code i came across trying to simplify the code further for stackoverflow, until i found it quadruple-clicked.

You have a playButton.addEventListener("click" inside a playButton.addEventListener("click" - same goes for idk.addEventListener("click" and aud.addEventListener('canplaythrough', init);. Avoid that. Create a different logic, or eventually use {once: true} for the inner clicks. Also, async is unnecessary.

The problem is that Chromium and Firefox hate when I put the play button's "click" event listener inside init (the listener function, not the addEventListener call). the answer  involves placing and defining that function anywhere outside of the Audio.oncanplaythrough event listener function, like so:
<!doctype html><html><body>
  <button id="play" disabled>play</button>
  <button id="idk">load audio</button>
  <script>
    var clicks = 0; console.clear();
    idk = document.getElementById("idk");
    idk.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{
      aud = new Audio("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3")
      aud.addEventListener('canplaythrough', init);
    }, {once: true});
    function playButtonClick(e){
      if(aud.paused){
        aud.play();
        playButton.innerText = "pause";
      }else{
        aud.pause();
        playButton.innerText = "play";
      }
      //Nothing different between duplicate click events, logging it takes up space
      console.log(clicks++, aud.paused, /*e*/);//clicks++ to tell apart logs.
    }
    function init(){
      /**/aud.playbackRate = 0.25;//only to lengthen the audio to give you time.
      playButton = document.getElementById("play");
      playButton.disabled = false;
      idk.innerText = "pause and set time to 1";
      playButton.addEventListener("click", playButtonClick);
      idk.addEventListener("click", e=>{
        console.log("Rightmost element clicked");
        if(!aud.paused){ aud.pause(); playButton.innerText = "play"; }
        aud.currentTime = 1;
      });
    }
  </script>
</body></html>


But now chrome is just messing with me, and now I have to do this to every nested click listener I ever face.

Here's a much cleaner approach:

Avoid creating event, functions, within other event functions, otherwise you'll end up incrementally stacking new callbacks on every event ("click"). One way is to use {once: true} as the Event options (third argument) - but that adds complexity to the code and it's hard to reason about and debug.
instantiate your variables properly (using const, let) to prevent polluting the global scope
set const aud = new Audio(); immediately in your variables. You'll add .source later
create three functions that do exactly what they say, namely: load() (with the specific pause + time thing), toggle() to toggle play/pause, and updateUI() which only job is to take care of the UI depending on the aud.paused and aud.readyState states
make use of the Audio "canplaythrough", "play" and "pause" Events in order to call the changeUI
Your load and play-pause Elements should (on click) call respectively the load() and toggle() functions



const source = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg";
const elLoad = document.querySelector("#load");
const elPlay = document.querySelector("#play");
const aud = new Audio(); // Set Audio constructor right away

// FUNCTIONS
const load = () => {
  aud.pause();
  if (aud.src !== source) aud.src = source;
  else aud.currentTime = 5;
};
const toggle = () => {
  aud[aud.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
};
const updateUI = () => {
  elPlay.disabled = !aud.readyState;
  elPlay.textContent = aud.paused ? "Play" : "Pause";
  elLoad.textContent = aud.readyState ? "Pause and set time to 5s" : "Load audio";
};

// EVENTS
aud.addEventListener("canplaythrough", updateUI);
aud.addEventListener("pause", updateUI);
aud.addEventListener("play", updateUI);
elLoad.addEventListener("click", load);
elPlay.addEventListener("click", toggle);

// INIT
updateUI();
<button id="play" disabled></button>
<button id="load"></button>




Way too complex and extreme on changes, but I have to give it to you on the first bullet. The first bullet was the only bullet that had an effect on wether or not it did what was expected. Still though, I'm busting my balls over why Chromium and Firefox hate nested inline function event listeners

It's in the word "add"; "addEventListener", not "overwriteEventListener". Sadly I cannot test on Safari, but I find it strange that such a common JS function would act so broken over there. You're welcome. Yes, the changes seem extreme, but It's actually way simpler now. Once I started properly extracting the listeners in one place, the functions in another - everything just asked to be properly rewritten, and reorganized. And if you look at the code nesting and complexity - besides some simple ternary operations ?: it all fitted like LEGOs and it's way more readable.

So to wrap it all up, Chrome and Firefox do use the addEventListener method properly - and creating listener inside a listener does indeed produce exactly what is expected - duplicate events added to the events stack queue.

So to wrap it all up, Chrome and Firefox do use the addEventListener method properly - and creating listeners inside a listener does indeed produce exactly what is expected - a bug. And it's even pretty logical. New events registered on every click, which lead to incremental or even exponential duplicates, depending on how deep you nest those listeners.
